# How do you avoid flexible array errors when you want to extend a structure with another in C/C++?

Tags: c++, flexible-array-member

I found this structure definition used to [handle detection of process changes in Linux](https://github.com/m2osw/eventdispatcher/blob/main/eventdispatcher/process_changed.cpp):

```
struct __attribute__((aligned(NLMSG_ALIGNTO))) event_message {
    nlmsghdr f_nl_hdr;
    struct __attribute__((__packed__)) {
        cn_msg f_cn_msg;
        proc_event f_proc_ev;
    } f_nl_msg;
};
```

That worked great.

Now that I'm moving forward to newer versions of the C++ compiler (g++12.2.0 as found in Ubuntu 23.04), I get an error saying that the flexible array member `__u8 data[]`, found in `cn_msg`, is not the last member as it ought to be:

> ```
> /usr/include/linux/connector.h: In member function ‘void ed::process_changed::listen_for_events()’:  
> /usr/include/linux/connector.h:78:14: error: flexible array member ‘cn_msg::data’ not at end of ‘struct ed::process_changed::listen_for_events()::multicast_message’  
>   78 |         __u8 data[];  
>      |              ^~~~
> ```

At the moment, I can't think of anything other than the following which adds a `malloc()`:

1. Computing the total size:

   ```
   constexpr std::size_t size(sizeof(nlmsghdr) + sizeof(cn_msg) + sizeof(proc_event));
   ```
2. Creating a simple buffer of `uint8_t`:

   ```
   std::vector<std::uint8_t> buffer(std::vector<std::uint8_t>(size));
   ```
3. And finally casting each location to the corresponding structure:

   ```
   nlmsghdr * header = reinterpret_cast<nlmsghr *>(buffer.data());
   cn_msg * msg = reinterpret_cast<cn_msg *>(header + 1);
   proc_event * event = reinterpret_cast<proc_event(msg + 1);
   ```

   *Note: reading the [`reinterpret_cast<T>()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast) documentation, I do not think that these are UB because they match (currently) case 5 which says it is exactly equivalent to `static_cast<cv T2*>(static_cast<cv void*>(expression))` and that is 100% safe as long as `T1*` (type of expression) has the same alignment requirements as `T2*` (and of course the bytes at location `T2*` represent a structure of type `T2`).*

But that looks rather ugly and prone to many mistakes.

What other solution would there be to handle this situation?

Also correct me if I'm wrong, it does not look like this is a warning (I do use `-Werror` because so many warnings are errors, but could use a `#pragma` to cancel this one if it were a warning).

*Note 1: I will not consider redefining the structures. Using the files found in `/usr/include` is important to make sure the current version of the system is used.*

*Note 2: The library is very specific to Linux and the code is not expected to run on other systems than Ubuntu compiling with g++. So portability is not an issue outside of that.*

Comment: @user17732522 The `proc_event` is appended and is the `data[...]`. Life was simple before that new error. So we could create a buffer that worked just fine on the stack because the event size was well defined. Now I get the error because that `data[0]` ends up in the middle of the sub-structure (and not at the very end of all the structures/sub-structures.

Comment: As was previously commented: C++ doesn't actually support flexible array members, so that's a showstopper there before you even start. If you're happy to work with non-portability (including possibly breakage by just updating system or even compiler) there might be workarounds available. Or maybe a possible workaround is to use a C function to translate the data into a new structure that can be passed or used by C++ code?

Comment: Is defining one's own, C++-compliant type and then serializing it into a system-defined C struct "redefining a structure"? Also, how much does portability matter?

Comment: The referenced library is none-portable anyway. It uses other none-std extensions such as designated array initializer list(`{[i]=x,}`). Lots of red flags. I'd switch to other solutions; because there will be huge amounts of such errors and run-time surprises with it.

Comment: Since a `cn_msg` has a flexible array member, you can't sanely put it in a struct with any other fields after it, as those following fields will end up overlaid into the flexible array.  So even without the warning/error, this is not going to work.

Comment: @ChrisDodd Actually, that seems to be the idea here. The following field provides the memory for the flexible array, allowing this to be allocated "on the stack" rather than malloc'ed. Some sort of variant record implementation without a union or malloc, but probably violating strict aliasing, if I am understanding correctly.